# Is there a Hoogle equivalent for DAML?

Tags: types, type-systems, daml

Hoogle comes handy to find an appropriate function in Haskell by typing the approximate type signature. Is there some similar support for DAML?

Answer (score 3):

Hoogle is integrated in the search on https://docs.daml.com, e.g., searching for `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b])` https://docs.daml.com/search.html?query=(a%20-%3E%20b)%20-%3E%20[a]%20-%3E%20[b] will bring up `map`.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a more familiar looking [Hoogle-for-DAML](https://hoogle.daml.com/) (though I argue it should be called Doogle!)